# How to dynamically generate information base on the iFrame content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a iFrame, that allow people to post information to the web server directly, but before he post, he must login first....like this:

```
________________________
[______I inject --->_X_]
|                      |
|     iFrame           |
|        Login         |
|                      |
________________________
```

I can hide the frame by click the X button, but after the user logined, I would like to have something like this:

```
________________________
[____________________X_]
|                      |
|    Post Your         |
|        Msg           |
|    (iFrame)          |
|                      |
________________[POST]__
```

It just like some clipper in some note taking program, when the user click the "post" button, the msg will be sent to server, also, the iFrame will be disappear. But I got a problems here....How can I paste the post button? It should in the iframe or client side, just like the X, I injected in the client side? 
If the post button is in the client side, I can add a hidden submit button in the Post Your msg iFrame form, when the user click it, I just make the user click the hidden submit button too. But the question is, when the user havn't sign in, I just have the Login, within a post button. But I can't detect what's going on inside the iFrame. How can I implement this post button? Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is create a div, position it in the center of the screen and give it a higher z-index so the box looks like it's floating. So we have a central floating box, inside the box you need 2 more boxes 1st being another div box (that will contain the X) and the second being the Iframe. For both do position:relative; float:left use matching widths and declare heights. From her you have your iframe & close button in separate worlds. To close you need to do something like

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#close').click(function(){
$('#box').hide();
});
});
```

Or use the css or animation function to get similar results instead of hide().
Hopefully this helps, unless I've mis understood something.

Comment: I can do it in the close button, but the post button, I can't. I don't know where to put the post button, whether in the iframe page or outside the iframe page. If I created in the iFrame page, how can it call itself to disappear, if it is created ourside the iframe page, how can I know that when do the page need a submit button or not, because it the user haven't logined, it should don't show the submit button.

Comment: There are some ways you can communicate the iframe to the main site though I wouldn't recommend doing this due to security reasons. Ted try to focus on the users needs rather than your wants. The user doesn't care about it disappearing automatically, it's just a convenience if it does...A close X button is not a hinder. If you're creative you can create alternative results though..I'm curious if it does disappear what do you want to be in place?

Comment: But others can make it happen, after they clip the site, they can hide it: http://blog.springpadit.com/2010/02/springpad-clipper/

Comment: Looks like a solution hope it works, though in my opinion you should avoid iframes unless necessary as a last result. Iframes are way over abused there's always an authentic method for implementing forms/ registrations/ post/ get.